# How do I request Postgres for counts for different dates from a certain time series?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of visits like this:

```
time                   | user_id
--------------------------------
2018-05-01 00:00:00+02 | 56
2018-05-01 00:00:00+02 | 64
2018-05-01 00:00:00+02 | 56
2018-05-02 00:00:00+02 | 27
2018-05-02 00:00:00+02 | 64
...
```

I want to request Postgres database for the quantity of active users per date. A user is active if he has visits at 10 separate dates for the previous 30 days. For example, for the quantity at date 2018-05-22 the query would be:

```
select count(*) from (
    select
        user_id,
        count(distinct time::date) as cnt
    from visit
    where
        time::date > '2018-05-22'::date - interval '30 days'
    group by user_id
    having count(distinct time::date) >= 10
    order by cnt desc
) t
```

The result is one number. It works correct. What should I modify in this query in order to obtain the quantities for each date from a certain time series? The required result should be like this:

```
date       | quantity
---------------------
2018-05-01 | 38
2018-05-02 | 26
2018-05-03 | 35
2018-05-04 | 44
...
```

Comment: I think you simply need `group by time::date, user_id` (unrelated but: a column named `time` that actually contains a `timestamp` and not a `time` seems rather confusing - especially if you think of an expression like `time::date`...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I think the OP wants the results of this query for each of the shown dates.  1st May and 30 days prior as first row, 2nd may and 30 days prior as second row, etc.  *(At present the query only does "parameterised date, and 30 days prior" as a single output row.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a calendar table, full of all of the dates you'll ever need.

Say, from `'1900-01-01'` to `'2099-12-31'`?

Then it's basically a `JOIN`...

```
SELECT
    calendar_date, count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CALENDAR_TABLE.calendar_date,
        visit.user_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT visit.time::date) as cnt
    FROM
        CALENDAR_TABLE
    INNER JOIN
        visit
            ON  visit.time >= CALENDAR_TABLE.calendar_date - interval '30 days'
            AND visit.time <  CALENDAR_TABLE.calendar_date + interval '01 days'
    WHERE
        CALENDAR_TABLE.calendar_date BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-22'
    GROUP BY
        CALENDAR_TABLE.calendar_date,
        visit.user_id
    HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT visit.time::date) >= 10
) t
GROUP BY
    calendar_date
```

Or perhaps...

```
SELECT
    calendar_date, count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CALENDAR_TABLE.calendar_date,
        visit.user_id,
        COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM
        CALENDAR_TABLE
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
           user_id,
           time::date   AS user_date
        FROM
           visit
        GROUP BY
           user_id,
           time::date
    )
        visit
            ON  visit.user_date >= CALENDAR_TABLE.calendar_date - interval '30 days'
            AND visit.user_date <  CALENDAR_TABLE.calendar_date + interval '01 days'
    WHERE
        CALENDAR_TABLE.calendar_date BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-22'
    GROUP BY
        CALENDAR_TABLE.calendar_date,
        visit.user_id
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) >= 10
) t
GROUP BY
    calendar_date
```

That may reduce memory overhead, but may make the joins and filtering slower...

Comment: Thank you. I like the idea, but it doesn't provide the correct result. Probably, you should join in the 30 days window? And I think you can replace the new table CALENDAR_TABLE with GENERATE_SERIES.

Comment: @Fomalhaut - You can generate it every time, but then you can't apply indexes and gain multiple other benefits from having a real table.  Considering it will take almost no space having a material table is nearly always the better option.  *(I've editted the answer now I'm not in a rush.)*

Comment: Is it possible to consume less memory? I am asking because such INNER JOIN takes too many records if the table `visit` has many rows (around 100k per day).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method uses `generate_series()`:

```
select g.dte, count(*)
from (select g.dte, v.user_id, count(distinct v.time::date) as cnt
      from generate_series('2018-05-01'::date, '2018-05-22'::date, interval '1 day') g(dte) left join
           visit v
           on v.time::date <= g.dte and
              v.time::date > '2018-05-22'::date - interval '30 days'
      group by g.dte, v.user_id
      having count(distinct v.time::date) >= 10
     ) vd
group by g.dte
order by g.dte;
```

If you have a large volume of data, there might be faster ways.  If that is an issue, ask another question.